# Saving remote IP with prepared stateents

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to save remote user IP in database. For the purpose I've created column as `int(10) UNSIGNED`.

When I try like this everything work but the IP is saved like `127.0.0.1`

```
$ipaddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO comment (body, author, email, date, url, ip) VALUES (:body, :author, :email, NOW(), :url, :ipaddr)');

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':body' => $_POST['k3jZGEeX1k1oo'],
    ':author' => $_POST['k3k0xKicU0eHQ'],
    ':email' => $email,
    'url' => $url,
    'ip' => $ipaddr
));
```

When I try to use `INET_ATON` nothing goes in database.

```
$ipaddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO comment (body, author, email, date, url, ip) VALUES (:body, :author, :email, NOW(), :url, :INET_ATON(ipaddr))');

$stmt->execute(array(
        ':body' => $_POST['k3jZGEeX1k1oo'],
        ':author' => $_POST['k3k0xKicU0eHQ'],
        ':email' => $email,
        'url' => $url,
        'ip' => $ipaddr
));
```

Note the `:INET_ATON(ipaddr)`. How can I do this with prepared statements?

Comment: `:INET_ATON` ? that is a built-in function https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_inet-aton why the colon? what you want is `INET_ATON(:ip)`

Comment: You should not use `int(10) UNSIGNED`. It is a "strange" number... you have 3 dots (`.`). So change it to `varchar(12)` -> `XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW` -> 12

Comment: @Fred-ii- I've tried also like this but then I've got `error 500`

Comment: check your logs then; something failed and use pdo's error checking

Comment: @Fred-ii- sorry my mistake it's not error 500. Just nothing saved in database. Same as `:INET_ATON(ipaddr)`

Comment: @matiaslauriti the idea is to not save it like `XXX.YYY.ZZZ.WWW` but like `1467557485`

Comment: again; you shouldn't be using a colon for that built-in function. If it's not going in db, use pdo's error handling http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php and php's error reporting http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php to see if anything comes of it. var_dump everything to see what's passing through or not and check your db's column types.

Comment: can't see why you didn't ping me back here. I basically gave you the solution a long time ago.

Comment: I have this in `try{}catch` where in the catch i have `var_dump ($e->getMessage());` but still nothing shown there as error. Ive tried bellow solution and it is working. Above no mater even when I removed the colons from the `INET_ATON` function still didn't insert in database.

Answer (score 0):

As @Fred-ii- stated you should check errors. I also can recommend [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2917000/1158599) and build in php function [ip2long](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ip2long.php). In your case will be

```
$ipaddr = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$ip = sprintf("%u", ip2long($ipaddr));

$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO comment (body, author, email, date, url, ip) VALUES (:body, :author, :email, NOW(), :url, :ip)');

$stmt->execute(array(
    ':body' => $_POST['k3jZGEeX1k1oo'],
    ':author' => $_POST['k3k0xKicU0eHQ'],
    ':email' => $email,
    ':url' => $url,
    ':ip' => $ip
));
```

To select and see actual IP you can then use `INET_NTOA`(again from the @Fred-ii- comment) in your query.

Comment: colon's are not needed in the arrays, only on the *very rare* occasion. However, the OP didn't say anything about my asking them in comments.

Comment: Actually you're correct. They are optional in the `execute()` and `bindParam()` calls. They are required only in `SQL statement`